# Dynamic TextView with storyboards and auto layout

Tags: ios, textview, storyboard, constraints, autolayout

I have a view which has on top a `UITextView` then a series of other views. The idea is to resize the Text View on its content size and to move up all the other views.

I have set all the constraints in storyboard and if I change the height constraint value of my TextView from there,  all the view updates fine.

On runtime I can resize the Text View frame to fit it's content size, but the rest of the view doesn't change. So I'm guessing I don't have to change the frame but only the height constraint.

Any suggestion on how is it possible to do this thing on runtime? 
How can I change the Height constraint value in code?
Is there any way to "link" a constraint to the controller from storyboard?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make an IBOutlet of height contraint from nib to your .h file.
Lets name it `textViewHeightConstraint`

```
self.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = textView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: This don't work for me, `textview.contentSize.height` doesn't return the right value.

Answer (score -1):

U need to set a textviews property Scrollable to false

Comment: That's neither the correct class name, nor the correct accessor name.